# python webserver socket programming error

Tags: python, sockets

```
# Import socket module
from socket import *

#from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, socket
import sys  # In order to terminate the program

# Create a TCP server socket
#(AF_INET is used for IPv4 protocols)
#(SOCK_STREAM is used for TCP)

ipadress=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
subnetAdress = '.'.join(ipadress.split('.')[:3]) + '.0'

print(f"ipadress : {ipaddress}")
print(f"subnetAdress : {subnetAdress}")


file = open("permit.txt", 'r', encoding="UTF-8")
permitList = file.readlines()

# 
    

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Assign a port number
serverPort = 6789
# Bind the socket to server address and server port
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
# Listen to at most 1 connection at a time
serverSocket.listen(1)
# Server should be up and running and listening to the incoming connections

while True:
    print('The server is ready to receive')
    # Set up a new connection from the client
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    # If an exception occurs during the execution of try clause
    # # the rest of the clause is skipped
    # # If the exception type matches the word after except
    # # the except clause is execute
    if subnetAdress+'\n' in permitList:
        print("Warning!!\n it's not permitted")
        continue
    try:
        # Receives the request message from the client
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(message)

        # Extract the path of the requested object from the message
        # # # The path is the second part of HTTP header, identified by [1]
        # filename = message.split()[1]

        print(filename)
        # Because the extracted path of the HTTP request includes
        # # # a character '\', we read the path from the second character
        file = open(filename[1:], 'rb')
        # Store the entire contenet of the requested file in a temporary buffer
        # outputdata = file.read()
        # # Send the HTTP response header line to the connection socket
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
        if(filename.endswith(".jpg")):
            filetype = 'image/jpg'
        elif(filename.endswith(".mp4")):
            filetype = 'video/mp4'
        elif(filename.endswith(".wmv")):
            filetype = 'video/wmv'
        elif(filename.endswith(".gif")):
            filetype = 'video/gif'
        elif(filename.endswith(".html")):
            filetype = 'text/html'
        else:
            raise IOError
        header += 'Content-Type: '+str(filetype)+'\n\n'
        print(header)
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())
        # Send the content of the requested file to the connection socket
        # # # for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
        # # # #     connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        # # # connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        # Close the client connection socket
        # connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        # Send HTTP response message for file not found
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \n\n'
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())
        connectionSocket.send(
        "<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html>\r\n".encode())
        # Close the client connection socket
        connectionSocket.close()
        serverSocket.close()
        sys.exit()
        #Terminate the program after sending the corresponding data
```

**I did this for socket programming
it's hard to explain but I had this error. and I put from socket import
please help me out. I don't know why
I will be dying ..**

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\taek\python\탐색\네트워크\과제3\IPwebServer.py in <module>
      9 #(SOCK_STREAM is used for TCP)
     10 
---> 11 ipadress=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
     12 subnetAdress = '.'.join(ipadress.split('.')[:3]) + '.0'
     13 

AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
                                                                                         **                                        **
```

ㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: if you use `from socket import *` then you have to do `gethostbyname` without `socket.`. If you use `import socket` then you can use `socket.gethostbyname`. BTW: `import *` is not preferred so better use `import socket` - but remeber that later you have to also use `socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)` instead of `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)`

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
from socket import *
```

then you have to use without `socket.`

```
gethostbyname(...)
gethostname()
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

---

If you use

```
import socket
```

then you have to use with `socket.`

```
socket.gethostbyname(...)
socket.gethostname()
socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

---

BTW: `import *` is not preferred - see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)